# How do I perform math in SQL query on certain conditions?

Tags: sql, if-statement, structure

I have a few tables I am querying, Item movement, and price.  There are three price levels, regular price, reduced price, and sale price.  I am attempting to get a markdown (price that item sold at when on sale minus either the regular or reduced price). My item movement table contains only the price the unit sold at and the price type of that sale.  I am currently selecting only the items that sold on the sale price type.  Next I have to find out whether the item was on a regular or reduced price, which I determine by looking at my price table.  The price table has my regular price and reduced price and if the reduced price is null then it is not currently reduced.

How do I tell SQL  that I want a column named "markdown" that is essentially (IF price.tprprice not null AND price.tprenddate > @StartDate give me column (price.baseprice - price.tprprice) * itemmovement.qtysold AS markdown ELSE give me column (price.baseprice - itemmovement.price) * itemmovement.qtysold AS markdown)

I need to return the result of each calculation performed on each row into the same column titled Markdown.

Can anyone tell me how this query should be structured?

Comment: You are probably going to need a case statement in your query to figure out what to return. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: What Database are you using? (MS-SQL, MySQl, Oracel or ...)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Express 2012.  Once I do a proof of concept I plan to upgrade to Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case when price.tprprice is not null AND price.tprenddate > @StartDate
     then (price.baseprice - price.tprprice) * itemmovement.qtysold 
else (price.baseprice - itemmovement.price) * itemmovement.qtysold 
end as markdown
```

You would do it with a `case` statement which works in most databases.

Comment: This looks like it works, it definitely doesn't throw any errors.  Now I just need to verify all the math. Thank you so much for the help!  New to SQL impressed every day at what it can do.